# unable to get iris colorpicker on jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/zu5uv650/4/

In my HTML window I have this:

```
<input type="text" id='color-picker' value="#bada55" />
```

In my JS window I have this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#color-picker').iris();
});
```

I'm using jQuery 2.1.0 as my framework and am using the following external resources:

http://automattic.github.io/Iris/javascripts/iris.min.js
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js
https://cdn.rawgit.com/Automattic/Iris/master/src/iris.css

...and I'm getting a `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` error. Any ideas?

Also, jquery UI has a CSS component too. Does jsfiddle.net really not have the ability to auto include JQuery UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your load order is incorrect: jQuery UI should come before the iris.min.js file. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emturano/vdmw1knL/).

```
jquery-ui.min.js
iris.min.js
iris.css
```